# Multi-select in a Django Model with another Model's thumbnails as attributes

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-multiwidget

Is there a way to pass a Django model's Images as attributes to a Multi-select select field in another Django Model? If not, is there any way to display thumbnails of a model in another model's ModelForm as multiple select options?